# Barium sulfide vs Ba2S2

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, ionic-compounds

I was predicting a very simple chemical equation
$$\ce{Ba + S ->}$$
And I had solved it as
$$\ce{Ba + S -> BaS}$$
The answer should make sense as barium has a charge of +2, and sulfide has a charge of −2; however, the book had said that the answer was
$$\ce{Ba + S -> Ba2S2}$$
I do indeed know how and why they got the answer, but I just want to know why my answer isn't correct, or if it is and I'm just acting silly.

Comment: Don't know what your book is saying, no such compound exists, whereas BaS is well-known https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barium_sulfide

Comment: see this:-http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/8438/reaction-between-zinc-and-sulfur

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As orthocresol pointed out, $\ce{Ba_2S_2}$ does not exist as it's own substance. Perhaps you've misread the question and it instead asks for something else? Otherwise it is wrong, or at least not simplified. Your answer is in effect the correct one, although I'm not sure if sulfur and barium would react like that exactly.

It might in addition generate multiple polysulfides, such as $\ce{BaS_2}$, $\ce{BaS_3}$, following the rule of $\ce{BaS_{$x$}}$. However, I believe your answer is correct in that the initial reaction between barium and sulfur would produce $\ce{BaS}$, while further reactions might add more sulfurs onto it.

Comment: BaS2 **does** exist, BaS3 and BaS4 too (also @ortho). You should not answer like that, I'm tempted to downvote you.

Comment: @Mithoron Alright. I can see what you mean, however, I do not know what exactly it would yield. My answer does not add any information on what the actual product would be, so I will likely remove it soon if I cannot come up with a better one.

Comment: @Mithoron It seems it might generate multiple polysulfides, as you mentioned. I will try and explain this well enough, but since my understanding is rudimentary, my answer might not be the best. If it is still not up to par, downvote and I'll remove it.

Comment: Welp, it has now been changed. I have received a downvote before the edit, so I will wait for one more.

Comment: Wait, there was Ba2S2... Oh my, sorry I didn't down vote you and question is bad. Oops!

Comment: @Mithoron Thanks for clearing it up. I'm relatively new to chemistry, so I am trying to make sure my answers are correct or do not exist.

Comment: [Obligatory poke towards using `\ce{...}`](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/3046)

Comment: "Exist" is not quite the right word. Why don't we write $\ce{BaS}$ as $\ce{Ba2S2}$, really? Sure, it does not contain isolated particles $\ce{Ba2S2}$, but it does not contain $\ce{BaS}$ particles either. It is not that $\ce{Ba2S2}$ is "not true"; it is that writing it like that **has no point**.

Comment: I am just curious to know if it would be a valid answer to give Ba2S2, instead of BaS. Since they both give the same ratio of Ba : S.

Comment: @Dan I would say no, not normally. As Ivan has pointed out it is true, but it is like saying the answer to 20 divided by 4 is $10/2$. This is correct, but not simplified.