# Reaction of sulphur and nitric acid

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox

I would like to ask a question about Sulfur in the reaction with Nitric Acid, $\ce{HNO3}$ to produce Sulfuric Acid, $\ce{H2SO4}$

I read that as Nitrogen and Sulfur are reduced and oxidised respectively, the reaction equation can be constructed as follows:

$\ce{S + 6HNO3 -> H2SO4 + 6NO2 + 2H2O}$

Now, when I read an article on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfur) regarding sulfur, the introductory paragraph states the following:

> Under normal conditions, sulfur atoms form cyclic octatomic molecules with a chemical formula $\ce{S8}$.

So why is sulfur represented in the equation as $\ce{S}$ and not $\ce{S8}$?

Comment: Because that doesn't make much of a difference. Sure, you may multiply everything by 8, if you'd like.

Comment: Just call $\ce{S}$ an empirical formula.  Empirical formulas work perfectly well in chemical reaction equations.

Comment: See this: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/8438/reaction-between-zinc-and-sulfur

Answer (score 1):

The most stable allotropic form of sulfur exists in the formula of S8. In other words, sulfur occurs naturally in S8 formula. Multiply all the stoicheomtric coefficient by 8 (other than S) to obtain the balanced chemical equation

Answer (score 0):

Balance the equation by taking S8.
Yes, it is true that naturally, sulfur does exist in S8 (crown sulfur) form.